# Knex.js .whereBetween() includes date before

Tags: javascript, express, eloquent, knex.js

I am running a filter query and getting records between a certain date range, for some reason, it's grabbing records a day before my range. For example:

```js
.whereBetween('created_at', [dateRange.from, dateRange.to]);
```

[image]

When I select `01/19/2022 - 01/26/2022` it grabs a record from `01/18/2022` for whatever reason, does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !!!

```
const result = await db('messages_logs as a')
      .join('users', 'a.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
      .select('a.*')
      .where('uuid', uuid)
      .whereRaw('date_format(a.createdAt, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN ? AND ?', [req.query.start, req.query.end]);
```